# Image gallery on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, responsive-design

I just created an image gallery, and I'm wondering how to make it responsive and work on mobile. https://willhay.io/photography/benches/ 
Right now if you pull it up on an iPhone it looks terrible. The image is taking up '100vh', so the height of the entire screen. In landscape mode it looks fine, although it zooms out strangely. In portrait mode, since the image is taking up 100% of the height of the screen, the width spills over and it does not fit the screen.

How would I make it so on mobile, it fills 100% of the width and is centered vertically?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<!--    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5" >  -->
    <title>Bay Trail Benches</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/photography.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>

<body>
        <a class="xButton" href="../../photography">✕</a>
        <a class="rightButton" href="../gazing-up">⇒</a>
        <a class="leftButton" href="../columns">⇐</a>
        <img class="wideImage" alt="benches" src="../images/benches.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.wideImage {
    height:100vh;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Change `width: auto;` to `width: 100%;`

Comment: That changes the aspect ratio of the image

Answer (score 0):

It requires some more CSS because your html isn't structured very well.

```
.wideImage {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    z-index: -1;
    margin:auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```